# How to export long strings from datasource to excel in Coldufusion and Report Builder

Tags: coldfusion, export-to-excel, reportbuilder

I have to export some data, stored in a MSSQL database, using Coldfusion server pages.

I setup my query with the *cfquery* tag, I generate my cfr file in Report Builder and setup the *cfreport* tag like this:

```
<cfquery name="q" datasource="mydsn"> SELECT * FROM table </cfquery>

<cfreport format="EXCEL" template="cfrPath/cfrfile.cfr" query="#q#" filename="mydir/myexcelfile.xls" overwrite = "yes"/>
```

By the way, it seems that Coldfusion cuts some fields, expecially the very long text ones.

It is a bug or miss something in my setup?

Answer (score 3):

At a guess, I'd say you need to either increase your text buffer or enable CLOBs in your DSN setup in ColdFusion Administrator.